# Angular: How to write a unit test for template variable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I'm working page auto scroll when click on the button and I'm using template variable as target point. How to write a unit testing for `scrollToSecondPage` function which has template var as param.

**app.component.html**

```
<section>
  <p>section 1</p>
  <button (click)="scrollToSecondPage(slide2)">Go to section 2</button>
</section>  
<section #slide2>
  <p>section 2</p>
</section>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
scrollToSecondPage(el: any): void {
  el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
it('should scroll down to section two', () => {
  let component = fixture.componentInstance;
  let spy = spyOn(component, 'scrollToSecondPage').and.callThrough();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Do you want to unit-test the behavior of `scrollToSecondPage` only, or do you want to do an integration test that clicks the button and checks for the appropriate behavior?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner, just for `scrollToSecondPage` behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to unit-test, this should do the trick.

```
import createSpy = jasmine.createSpy;

it('should scroll down to section two', () => {
  let component = fixture.componentInstance;
  const scrollSpy = createSpy('scrollIntoView')
  const el = {
    scrollIntoView: scrollSpy,
  }

  component.scrollToSecondPage(el);

  expect(scrollSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ behavior: 'smooth' });
});
```

You will create a spy that you can check for calls, which you pass to the method and check if the spy has been called by the component afterwards.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks @philipp